# Importing Eclipse Android projects into Titanium Studio

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, titanium

I'm trying to import an Eclipse Android project into Titanium Studio.
In Titanium Studio I've used File --> Import --> Android --> Existing Android code into workspace.

After the import phase, I have the same structure of the Eclipse Project (src, res, gen, etc.).

If I run the project pressing directly the green button, Titanium shows me a popup asking me something (I've choose "Android Application") and then the android emulator starts successfully and the application runs correctly.

I've configured the "Run Configuration" adding iOS & Android configurations.

But, when I launch the Android or iOS configuration, Titanium Studio shows a popup with this message:

> **The requested SDK version does not have an assigned commands-handler**

I've also "cleaned" the project and made a refresh without results.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.